# Implement an Umbraco/ASP.NET password validation script in Ruby / Python

Tags: python, asp.net, ruby, umbraco

I have exported about 1K users from an Umbraco database. We have emails and hashed_passwords for each. There appears to be no per-user salt.

Umbraco project version is 7.4 with the following (default) settings:

```
<membership defaultProvider="UmbracoMembershipProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="UmbracoMembershipProvider" type="Umbraco.Web.Security.Providers.MembersMembershipProvider, Umbraco.Web" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" minRequiredPasswordLength="5" useLegacyEncoding="false" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="false" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" defaultMemberTypeAlias="Member" passwordFormat="Hashed" allowManuallyChangingPassword="true" />
    <add name="UsersMembershipProvider" type="Umbraco.Web.Security.Providers.UsersMembershipProvider, Umbraco.Web" />
  </providers>
</membership>
<!-- Role Provider -->
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="UmbracoRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="UmbracoRoleProvider" type="Umbraco.Web.Security.Providers.MembersRoleProvider" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
<machineKey validationKey="9FEB5*******************B7348B27A6C" decryptionKey="73934**************69366" validation="HMACSHA256" decryption="AES" />
```

Asp.net code used seems to be this one:

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/Security/SQLMembershipProvider.cs,f37d42faca2b921e,references

I have setup this code in Ruby to properly encode the plain text password and compare it with the hashed passwords, so that users can login without having to reset their original plain text passwords:

```
def encode_password(password, salt)

    require "base64"
    require "digest"

    bytes = ""
    password.each_char { |c| bytes += c + "\x00" }
    salty = Base64.decode64(salt)
    concat = salty+bytes
    sha256 = Digest::SHA256.digest(concat)
    encoded = Base64.encode64(sha256).strip()
    puts encoded
  end
```

But my problem is that I don't know which salt to use.
From what I've been able to research here:

https://shazwazza.com/post/umbraco-passwords-and-aspnet-machine-keys

Umbraco uses a single salt derived from the machineKey, but it's unclear which part exactly. And it's unclear if it should be part of the `validationKey` or the `decryptionKey`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the salt is not based on the machine key. The blog post says:

> The key used to hash the passwords is the generated salt we produce it is not the key part of the Machine Key

and

> The part of the Machine Key that is used to hash the passwords is specifically the algorithm type.

So the only part of the machine key that is used is the algorithm type.

This method [`EncryptOrHashNewPassword`](https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/blob/8d96c6e842116e4a8c28547ac3cc08d5c78dee24/src/Umbraco.Core/Security/MembershipProviderBase.cs#L790) is what creates the salt + password. It then calls [`EncryptOrHashPassword`](https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/blob/8d96c6e842116e4a8c28547ac3cc08d5c78dee24/src/Umbraco.Core/Security/MembershipProviderBase.cs#L687) with the provided salt to do the password hashing. All of that is called from this method [`HashPasswordForStorage`](https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/blob/8d96c6e842116e4a8c28547ac3cc08d5c78dee24/src/Umbraco.Core/Security/MembershipProviderBase.cs#L25) which takes the fully hashed password along with the salt used to hash the password and stores both of them together as a string (base64 iirc).

When verifying the password, the salt is [parsed from the stored string](https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/blob/8d96c6e842116e4a8c28547ac3cc08d5c78dee24/src/Umbraco.Core/Security/MembershipProviderBase.cs#L826) and is used to hash the incoming password to see if they match. [This unit test somewhat shows this](https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/blob/8d96c6e842116e4a8c28547ac3cc08d5c78dee24/src/Umbraco.Tests/Membership/UmbracoServiceMembershipProviderTests.cs#L175)

That's pretty much what you would need to port to Ruby/Python.

Comment: Trying to understand. The code itself is extremely helpful. I see that function CheckPassword(string password, string dbPassword) takes the plain text password and the db hashed password as params. Then it calls this: var storedHashedPass = StoredPassword(dbPassword, out salt); to get the salt string from dbpassword. But then things get weird, because it calls var saltLen = GenerateSalt(); and this in turn calls var numArray = new byte[16]; new RNGCryptoServiceProvider().GetBytes(numArray); That last bit does not make sense. Because if the salt is random, it will never match hashed db password

Comment: Wait I think I got it. The random string is only generated for NEW passwords. If you're hashing a plain text password to compare to hashed dbPassword it only uses the length (saltLen.Length), which is always 16 right?

Comment: I've updated the answer with a better description/more links. But yes, a salt is only ever created when creating a new password, else the existing one is used to hash incoming passwords to check if the stored one matches.

Comment: In this case, the salt length was always 24. The first 24 bytes of the hashed_password to be exact.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is looking to export their Umbraco passwords hashes to an alternate platform, this is the Python script that made it possible for us to do the comparison with plain text passwords entered at login time. Working flawlessly.

```
import base64
import hashlib
import hmac
import secrets
from typing import Tuple

def check_password(password: str, db_password: str) -> bool:
    """Check if password matches"""

    if not db_password.strip():
        raise ValueError("dbPassword cannot be none or empty")

    stored_hash_password, salt = stored_password(db_password)
    hashed = encrypt_or_hash_password(password, salt)
    return stored_hash_password == hashed


def stored_password(stored_string: str) -> Tuple[str, str]:
    """Return salt and password from stored_string"""
    if not stored_string.strip():
        raise ValueError("stored_string cannot be none or empty")

    salt = GenerateSalt()
    salt_len = len(salt)
    
    password = stored_string[salt_len :]
    salt = stored_string[0 : salt_len - 1]

    return password, salt


def GenerateSalt() -> str:
    """Return byte array with 24 length"""
    return secrets.token_hex(12)


def encrypt_or_hash_password(password: str, salt: str) -> str:
    """Return hashed password"""

    ##
    ## Bytes with 16 length repeated till 64 length (=== is for base64 padding)
    ##
    salt_bytes = base64.b64decode(salt + '===') * 4 

    ## WARN!!!!
    ## HACK TO MATCH C# UNICODE
    ##
    unicode_password = []
    for char in password:
        unicode_password += char
        unicode_password += chr(0)
    password_bytes = ''.join(unicode_password).encode()

    hash_bytes = hmac.new(salt_bytes, password_bytes, digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest()
    return base64.b64encode(hash_bytes).decode()

print(
    check_password(
        "xxxxxx",
        "aOrcTkUrkb45kR6UA7Yv5Q==S++GZlit8lIxxx2rpHDwPt3dhSoEDa3HPsUg4hCpnWU=",
    )
)
```